# how do i add these dict in one single array

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:@{@"Name": self.txt1.text , @"Roll No.":self.txt2.text,}];

NSMutableDictionary *dict1= [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:@{@"Name":self.txt3.text , @"Roll No.":self.txt4.text}];

NSMutableDictionary *dict2 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:@{@"Name":self.txt5.text , @"Roll No.":self.txt6.text}];

NSMutableDictionary *dict3 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:@{@"Name":self.txt7.text, @"Roll No.":self.txt8.text}];
```

How do i add these dictionary in  single array...

Comment: @[dict1, dict2, dict3]

Answer (score 1):

Add objects(dictionaries) in array as following:-

```
NSArray *arrayData = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:dict,dict1,dict2,dict3, nil];
```

//Show values in other view controller (as per comment)NSDictionary :-

Traverse the array, get the values, show the values in labels(IBOutlets)

```
*dicData = [arrayData objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *name = [dicData objectForKey:@"Name"];
    NSString *rollNo = [dicData objectForKey:@"Roll No."];
    labelName.text = name;
    labelRollNo.text = rollNo;
```

Comment: how do show this name and roll no entered through txtfield in labels in other viewcontroller

Comment: @swativerma, Pass the array to other view controller. Traverse the array and show the values(name, roll no). Check [updated answer for reference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/44105288/988169).

Answer (score 0):

```
attributes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[attributes addObject: dict.mutableCopy];
[attributes addObject: dict1.mutableCopy];
[attributes addObject: dict2.mutableCopy];
[attributes addObject: dict3.mutableCopy];
```

that's it

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
NSMutableArray *arrDict = [NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@{@"Name" : self.txt1.text , @"Roll No" : self.txt2.text},@{@"Name" : self.txt7.text, @"Roll No" : self.txt8.text} nil
```

Using NSArray Literal

```
NSArray *arrDict =@[@{@"Name" : self.txt1.text , @"Roll No" : self.txt2.text},@{@"Name" : self.txt7.text, @"Roll No" : self.txt8.text} ];
```

**In Next ViewController you can get this dictionary through loop**

```
for (NSDictionary *dicUser in arrDict) {
        // this dictionary which contained by arrDict
        UILabel *lblName = [dicUser objectForKey:@"Name"];
        UILabel *lblRollNumber = [dicUser objectForKey:@"Roll No"];

    }
```

Comment: how do show this name and roll no entered through txtfield in labels in next viewcontroller

Comment: you need to pass this array to nextViewController and using loop you need to get this dictionary . and assign value to label using Value for key